# Opening a page in Webview by passing URL parameters

Tags: java, android, parameters, webview

I am working on an Android Application that opens an HTML page  in a webview within the app. The HTML page is stored in the assets folder and I call it by means of

```
loadUrl("file:///android_asset/a.html");
```

Now, the page is such that it accepts parameters from the URL (javascript). I need to know how do we pass URL parameters to this html file that is stored inside the assets folder. Writing them like this:

```
loadUrl("file:///android_asset/a.html?q=2&w=3");
```

doesn't work.
Is there any other way?

Riya

Answer (score 2):

If your HTML page handles the parameters via javascript (and i can't think of any other way it can handle them), you can call a javascript function in your code with the parameters after the page is loaded, and pass parameters to it.

```
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  

    @Override  
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  {  
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { setParameters(2,3)})()");  
        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/a.html");
```

Comment: All right, let me try it. I will let you know. Thanks, by the way, for the prompt answer.

Comment: Hey, I did try it but ran into another issue. My javascript page uses this to handle parameters: 

'var sURL = window.document.URL.toString();'

This doesn't work. Is there any other way to handle parameters? My exact need is to pass a string to the javascript function.

Comment: you don't need to get the parameters from the url, just get them from the function. also (maybe, haven't tested), you can override windows.document.URL and put your own value.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the method suggested by shaish and many others for passing url parameters to an 'asset folder' url. It seems that this is a well known bug for android 3 and 4 (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535). Simply calling webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/a.html?q=2&w=3") works on a blackberry 10 simulator.

Answer (score 1):

A similar explanation like shaish but adapted to my own case:

My problem was that anytime I switched to another app, when coming to the webapp, the webview kept reloading. I guess that's because of the following line in my `onCreate()` method: `myWebView.loadUrl(url);` I had the idea to pass these state variables in the url, but as you know it is not possible yet. 
What I did was to save the state of some variables using `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {...}` and restore them with `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){...}`.

In onCreate method after setting up myWebView I did the following:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String urlString)
{
     Log.i("onPageFinished", "loadVariables("+newURL+")");
     if(newURL!="")
         myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:loadVariables("+"\""+newURL+"\")");
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
});

jsInterface = new JSInterface(this,myWebView);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "Android");

if (savedInstanceState != null)
{
// retrieve saved variables and build a new URL
newURL = "www.yoururl.com";
newURL +="?var1=" + savedInstanceState.getInt("key1");
newURL +="?var2=" + savedInstanceState.getInt("key2");
Log.i("myWebApp","NEW URL = " + newURL);
}
myWebView.loadUrl("www.yoururl.com");
```

So, what it happens is that first I load the page and then I pass the variables when the page finished to load. 
In javascript `loadVariables` function looks like this:

```
function loadVariables(urlString){
    // if it is not the default URL
    if(urlString!="www.yoururl.com")
    {
        console.log("loadVariables: " + urlString);
        // parse the URL using a javascript url parser (here I use purl.js)
        var source = $.url(urlString).attr('source');
        var query = $.url(urlString).attr('query');  
        console.log("URL SOURCE = "+source + " URL QUERY = "+query);
        //do something with the variables 
    }
}
```